# Python console closes before program runs

Tags: python

When I run my program it seems like it doesn't even run at all, and just closes the console. It works just fine in the IDE, and a program very similar to it also works just fine.

Yes there is an input() at the very end, but there should be a lot before it reaches that, code:

```
import random
import os

words_list=[]

def player1_word():
    words=open("hangman_words.txt","a")
    p1_word=input("Player1, enter a word: ")
    words.write(p1_word.lower()+"\n")
    words.close()

def player2_word():
    words=open("hangman_words.txt","a")
    p2_word=input("Player2, enter a word: ")
    words.write(p2_word.lower()+"\n")
    words.close()

def game_word():
    words=open("hangman_words.txt","r")
    for line in words:
        words_list.append(line[0:len(line)-1])
    word=random.choice(words_list)
    words.close()
    return word

player1_word()
player2_word()
word=game_word()

guesses=5
word_length=[]
entered_letters=[]
incorrect_letters=[]
for i in range(len(word)):
    word_length.append('_')
print (word_length)
letter_remaining=len(word)

while guesses!=0:
    error=len(word)
    guess_word=input("Enter a letter: ")
    for i in range(len(word)):
        if word_length[i]==guess_word:
            print("Enter a letter that has not been entered before")
            break
        elif word[i]==guess_word:
            word_length[i]=word[i]
            letter_remaining-=1
        elif word[i]!=guess_word:
            error-=1
    if error==0:
        guesses-=1
    print (word_length)
    print ("Remaining Guesses:",guesses)
    if letter_remaining==0:
        print("Congrats! You got the word '", word, "' with" , guesses, "guesses remaining")
        break
    elif guesses==0:
        print("You lose, the word was '", word, "'")
        break
input()
```

should work like a normal hangman game, still need a second player function to build into it, but if it doesn't work in the console now, why should it later?

Comment: It's probably failing with an error. How are you running it? Open a command console and run it using `python`. My guess though is it's a file not found error. You're using relative paths.

Comment: If you're running it by double-clicking on the `.py` file, try opening a command prompt/terminal and running `python <your file>.py`.

Comment: @Tomothy32 i did the command in cmd and it does the same thing

Comment: @DoomSkull A command prompt won't just close in my experience. Manually open a fresh console and manually type the command in.

Comment: If you execute `python --version`, what comes up? Also, what exactly happened when you used `cmd`?

Comment: @Tomothy32 the version is 3.6.4.  When using cmd, i type run python FILENAME.py  and then it does the same as when double clicking on the .py file, starts the console, and instantly closes it

Comment: Then it's `python3 file_name.py`.

Comment: You are saying it starts a new console? It should execute the program in the current one.

Comment: @Rahul returns an error saying windows cannot find python3

Comment: @DoomSkull try online compilers, or try https://repl.it/

Comment: @Tomothy32 Ok so i got it to start a new console and run by giving it the file location rather than just python and filename, however now it doesn't open the .txt file specified in the code and only works with the inputs I give it at that moment

Comment: @DoomSkull Put something like `os.path.join(__file__, 'hangman_words.txt')` to get the actual path to the file, it's looking in wherever your console is set to.